# travis-ci GitHub release upload is unauthorized

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-delivery, github-release

I am trying to automate uploading binaries of C++ library as GitHub Releases with Travis-CI. The release is set up to proceed with encrypted token from a user with admin privileges on repository.
Everything is according to the docs, but still getting my builds failed with this error:

```
`on_complete': GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)
```

Please see details at: https://api.travis-ci.com/v3/job/161301399/log.txt

Let me clarify how I set up a release:

```
$ travis login
    # Answer the security challenge with GitHub username/password
$ travis setup releases --com 
    # Answer the security challenge with GitHub username/password
    # Answer few more questions
```

I do the `--com` part since the repository was recently moved to travis-ci.com and the job is performed there. However, I also tried the `--pro` and `` (no option, default to .org).

So here is deploy section of my .travis.yml:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  draft: true
  overwrite: true
  api_key:
    secure: [... omitted ...]
  file: ${DISTRIBUTION_NAME}
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

As for now I've run out of options, so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, I would like to be able to debug the problem.

* Can I manage the GitHub tokens somewhere? 
* Or at least see that some are issues and travis has an access to those?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after banging my head against the wall for the straight 3 hours, it come to my attention that I was encrypting OAuth token as secret for different repo.

Namely, `travis setup releases` (and updated .travis.yml) mentioned `Multy-io/Multy-back` while I was working on script for `Multy-io/Multy-Core` project.

This is leftover from setting up previous project. Please note that you might want to explicitly set the repository to avoid similar issue with:

`with travis setup releases -r Name/Repo`